# Unable to retrieve the data from Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In my project I am getting response from the server in the form

```
response:  

     <JKArray 0x7fa2e09036b0>(
        {
            id = 23;
            name = "Name1";    
        },
        {
            id = 24;
            name = "Name2";   
        }

    )
```

From this response array i am retrieving the objects at different indexes and then adding them in a mutableArray and then into a  contactsDictionary.

```
  self.contactsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    

            for(int i=0 ; i < [response count] ; i++)
            {
                NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [mutableArray addObject:[response objectAtIndex:i]];

                [self.contactsDictionary setObject:mutableArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];

            }
```

I want to retrieve data for Key @"name" from the contactsDictionary at some other location in the project. So how to do it.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the wrong way like you are setting your contactsDictionary.

replace below line

```
[self.contactsDictionary setObject:mutableArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
```

with

```
[self.contactsDictionary setObject:[mutableArray objectAtIndex :i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
```

becuase everytime your array have new objects so your contacts dictionary's first value have one object then second value have two object. so you shouldn't do that.

now, if you want to retrieve `name` then call like

```
 NSString *name = [[self.contactsDictionary objectForKey : @"1"]valueForKey : @"name"];
```

avoid syntax mistake if any because have typed ans here.

**Update as per comment:**

just take one mutablearray for exa,

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [arr addObject : name];  //add name string like this
```

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Aloha from your respond I can give you answer Belo like that according to you response.

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrRes count];i++);
{
   NSString *strId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrRes obectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"id"]];
   NSString *StrName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrRes objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]];

   NSLog(@"The ID is -%@",strId);
   NSLog(@"The NAME is - %@",strName);

  }
```